# iterating and replacing item at the same time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have an array and as I iterate through the array I wanted to replace the item as well. Is this not possible and will cause crahes if I do so? Here's the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [highlightItemsArray count]; i++){
   //replace the from array with the new one
   NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:highlightItem];
   [tempDictionary setObject:[newHighlightItem objectForKey:@"from"] forKey:@"from"];
   [highlightItemsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:tempDictionary];
   [indexes addIndex:i];
}
```

just wanted to know if this is legit in objective-C? if not then what is the alternative of doing so?

Comment: it will not cause any crash

Comment: This would only fail if you were using 'fast enumeration' (`for id object in array { }`). There might be a briefer way to accomplish what you're doing, but I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You above code look good.

If it crashes it is not due to altering of your array.

However in old style loops ( while, for(;;), dowhile ) you can change any of these 
   1. initialiser (but this is executed just once)
   2. counter
   3. condition.

But in case of fast enumeration you can not do all these.

Therefore if you incorporate your above code with for(... in ...) it will throw an  error, saying trying to mutate an immutable object. Even though you define your counter and/or array immutable fast enumeration treats them as immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way to solve that would be an array copy, i.e.

```
NSMutableArray *higlightItemsCopy = [highlightItemsArray mutableCopy];
for (int i = 0; i < [highlightItemsArray count]; i++){
   //replace the from array with the new one
   NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:highlightItem];
   [tempDictionary setObject:[newHighlightItem objectForKey:@"from"] forKey:@"from"];
   higlightItemsCopy[i] = tempDictionary;
   [indexes addIndex:i];
}
highlightItemsArray = higlightItemsCopy;
```

Haven't tested it, but something like that